# Why won't my JTable let me insert an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, imageicon

Pretty simple, I tried following some other questions here on how to modify the JTable to take an imageIcon. I have an image in my package called successIcon.png.

This is the code for my JTable, mostly auto-generated by Net Beans:

```
statusTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

statusTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
new Object [][] {

},
new String [] {
    "Icons", "Message"
}
) {
Class[] types = new Class [] {
    javax.swing.ImageIcon.class, java.lang.String.class
};
boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
    false, false
};

public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return types [columnIndex];
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return canEdit [columnIndex];
}
});
```

One of my buttons uses a static command from another .java file:

```
  DBCommands.executeCommand(sqlArea.getSelectedText(), (DefaultTableModel) statusTable.getModel(), selectArea);
```

This is the method signature for the method it calls. This command is called fine, I'm including it just in case:

```
public static void executeCommand(String command, DefaultTableModel model, 
         JTextArea selectArea){
```

That command passes it into a method called printStatus which is supposed to update the JTable, but it isn't working. At first under icon it would print "successIcon.png", but with my current code it doesn't put anything there at all:

```
public static void printStatus(String message, String command, PrintWriter statFileWriter, DefaultTableModel model){

    Object[] row = new Object[2]; // so I can add row to table

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("successIcon.png"); 

    row[0] = icon;
    row[1] = message + " (" + command + ")" + "\n";
    model.addRow(row);
   }
```

Comment: Did you try the default example? http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/InsertarowtoatablethroughDefaultTableModelatspecifiedrow.htm

Comment: I don't understand how that would be different from what I'm trying. The example uses the insertRow() method instead of addRow(), which would be hard for me to implement already since I need to append. Additionally they just added an Object array, which is what I'm trying to add as well, except mine has an ImageIcon that won't show up

Comment: Does the image load?  Try adding it to a label and adding it the screen as test

Comment: There's no image at all there. The images load fine for my JButtons

Comment: No image _where_? In the object referenced by `icon` or in the file named `"successIcon.png"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, my quick an nasty test works...

[image: Working Images]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private final JTable statusTable;

        public TestPane() {
            statusTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
            statusTable.setRowHeight(200);

            statusTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                    new Object[][]{},
                    new String[]{
                        "Icons", "Message"
                    }
            ) {
                Class[] types = new Class[]{
                    javax.swing.ImageIcon.class, java.lang.String.class
                };
                boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                    false, false
                };

                public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                    return types[columnIndex];
                }

                public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                    return canEdit[columnIndex];
                }
            });
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(statusTable));

            JButton add = new JButton("Add");
            add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) statusTable.getModel();
                    Object[] row = new Object[2]; // so I can add row to table

                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("successIcon.jpg");

                    row[0] = icon;
                    row[1] = "Boo";
                    model.addRow(row);
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

**Cavets**

- The `successIcon.jpg` MUST be in the same directory that the program is executed from (AKA the working directory)

## Conclusions

- The image isn't been loaded.  This is likely because where you think the image is, isn't where it is.  I prefer to use `ImageIO.read` to load images because it won't return until the image is fully loaded and it will throw an exception if the image can't be found
- You should use embedded resources instead of loading resource off the disk. I'd recommend this because the "working" context of the program can change and isn't always the same location that the program is installed
- The reference of the `JTable` your passing is not the same reference on the screen. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response. I had the .png's in the src for my program in NetBeans, and it was finding some of them properly as I was using some of them for button icons so I thought that was fine. However, I moved the successIcon.png to the parent directory and now it works! I also edited to pass in the JTable itself and only cast it to a DefaultTableModel at the end which seems like better practice.

Comment: So, when the images are in the `src` directory (embedded), you need to use `Class#getResource` to obtain a reference to them